# Jquery, how can I reduce the flicker?

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/caMvN/1/

when you hover over the green area, it is supposed to show two text fields. Now what I want to achieve is, when I hover over the green area, or the input fields, they should be visible without the flicker. Also if some text has been entered into the text fields, and I hover out, there should be a delay or timer before the fields disappear....

Any idea how this can be done with jquery?

Comment: It's occurring when your mouse moves over the 1px edge of the form element. Not sure how to fix it though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent the flicker, just use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead:

```
$("#back2").mouseenter(function(){
  $("form").fadeIn(100);
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $("form").hide();
});
```

And for the delay, you can do something like:

```
$("#back2").mouseenter(function(){
  $("form").fadeIn(100);
}).mouseleave(function(){
    if ($('#inp1').val() != ""){
        setTimeout(function() {$("form").hide()}, 500);
    } else {
        $("form").hide();
    }
});
```

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/QNJjP/) a working example

Update using `hover` in response to comments below:

```
$("#back2").hover(function(){
    $("form").fadeIn(100);
}, function(){
    if ($('#inp1').val() != ""){
        $setTimeout(function() {$("form").hide()}, 500);
    } else {
        $("form").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: or `.hover(funcIn, funcOut)` as a shortcut. Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/caMvN/3/

Comment: Or [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/#hover1), [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/yDjyF/) which takes the two handler as arguments.

Comment: That seems to make it worse. Move your mouse around over the input field and it goes nuts. (In Chrome at least).

Comment: @Shawn Chin, At least we were saying the same :)

Answer (score 1):

Change your first line to:

```
$("form").hide().mouseover(function(){$(this).show();});
```